# React-Native Image Opacity giving opacity to text

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Im using an image as basically a view and putting text inside of it, i tried to give opacity to the image but everytime i try the text gets opacity too I don't really know why it happens

[image]

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{height: 180,}}>
     <Image source={{uri : this.state.fullURLImage}} style={{flex: 1,width: window.width,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',opacity: 0.7}}>
       <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontWeight: 'bold',color:'white',fontSize:16,}}>{this.state.title}</Text>
       <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:14,}}>{'\n'}July {this._try(this.state.day)} | {this.state.time_start} - {this.state.time_end}</Text>
     </Image>
  </View>

  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'white',}}>
     <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'#1B3D6C',fontWeight:'bold',margin:10,marginTop: 40}}>{this.state.author}</Text>
     <Text style={{margin:10,textAlign: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'justify' : 'left'}}>{this.state.text}</Text>

  </View>
  <Image
     source={{uri : this.state.fullURLAuthor}}
     style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 180 - 64 / 2,
        height: 64,
        width: 64,
        left: (Dimensions.get('window').width - 64) / 2,
        borderRadius: 32,
     }}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: Please give opacity 1 to text i think it will solve you issue.

Problem is this text is inside image tag so whole area take opacity of parent in this image.

Comment: doesn't work still the same

Comment: You need to put Text outside of image tag and give them position

Comment: Also give opacity using like {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}}

Comment: Ok i solved it out with your sugestion with the text outside of image and giving them position! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put Text outside of image tag and give them position

OR

Also give opacity using like `{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'}}`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `<ImageBackground>` instead of `<Image>` and apply opacity and color as mentioned below.

```
                            <ImageBackground
                                style={{flex: 1,height: 110,resizeMode: 'cover',}}
                                source={imageSoure}
                                borderRadius={5}
                                resizeMode='cover'
                                imageStyle={{ opacity: 0.3,backgroundColor: 'YourFavouredColor'}}
                            >
                                <Text>
                                    {someText}
                                </Text>
                                <Text>
                                    {someOtherText}
                                </Text>
                            </ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Nisarg already mentioned, it's nice to position the text from outside of the image. And meanwhile here is the code for changing opacity for the background:

```js
<Image
  style={{
    resizeMode: "contain",
    height: 100,
    width: 200,
    opacity:0.1
  }}
  source={require("@expo/snack-static/react-native-logo.png")}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

React draws components in order of appearence.

That said, I think your Image is being drawn on top of Text.

You have more than one way to achieve your layout, but following your code try this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <Image
     source={{uri : this.state.fullURLAuthor}}
     style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 180 - 64 / 2,
        height: 64,
        width: 64,
        left: (Dimensions.get('window').width - 64) / 2,
        borderRadius: 32,
     }}
  />
  <View style={{height: 180,}}>
     <Image source={{uri : this.state.fullURLImage}} style={{flex: 1,width: window.width,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',opacity: 0.7}}>
       <Text style={{textAlign: 'center',fontWeight: 'bold',color:'white',fontSize:16,}}>{this.state.title}</Text>
       <Text style={{color:'white',fontSize:14,}}>{'\n'}July {this._try(this.state.day)} | {this.state.time_start} - {this.state.time_end}</Text>
     </Image>
  </View>

  <View style={{flexGrow: 1, backgroundColor: 'white',}}>
     <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'#1B3D6C',fontWeight:'bold',margin:10,marginTop: 40}}>{this.state.author}</Text>
     <Text style={{margin:10,textAlign: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'justify' : 'left'}}>{this.state.text}</Text>

  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: that didn't work , the problem i dont think is the rounded image , the problem is the <Image and the text inside it, i give opacity to image and the text gets it too